# Suppress tag creation of simple_form with HAML in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, simple-form

I am trying to create a form with the simple_form gem in a Ruby on Rails application and have the following problem:

Here is the intended output:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
   <input type="text" placeholder="Your email" />
   <input type="text" placeholder="Your password" />
   <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

and here is how I tried implementing it:

```
= simple_form_for User.new do |f|
   = f.input :email, required: true, placeholder: "Your email"
   = f.input :password, required: true, placeholder: "Your password"
   = f.submit "Register"
```

That generates a lot of other code as well (e.g. labels) which I don't want (I know it's bad SEO wise).

How can I suppress the creation of e.g. the  tag and get an output just like the one in the first block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that you can set them to false like so:

```
= simple_form_for User.new do |f|
   = f.input :email, required: true, placeholder: "Your email", label: false
   = f.input :password, required: true, placeholder: "Your password", label: false
   = f.submit "Register"
```